# Object doesn't support property or method 'slider' (jquery in Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint

I'm getting the error Object doesn't support property or method 'slider' when loading my Sharepoint page.

I'm running this function on page load

```
function sliderFunctionality() {
$("#sliderdiv").css("background-color", "#ccc");
$("#sliderdiv").slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
    }
});
$("#amount").val("$" + $("#sliderdiv").slider("value"));
alert('testing.....');
};
```

Here is my webpart code

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        //REGISTER STYLESHEETS
        CssRegistration.Register("/_layouts/STYLES/Stylesheet1.css");

        //REGISTER JAVASCRIPT LIBRARIES
        ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/SCRIPTS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);
        ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/SCRIPTS/jquery.SPServices-0.7.0.min.js", false);
        ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/SCRIPTS/JScript1.js", false);

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<label for='amount'>Donation amount ($50 increments):</label>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p><input type='text' id='amount' style='border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;' />"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div id='sliderdiv'>here</div></p>"));

        this.ChildControlsCreated = true;
    }
```

The change of css background colour works but the slider doesn't.  So jquery is working fine on the page and the DIV is being found.

Why is slider not working?  I'm using jquery 1.7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you're pulling in the jQuery-UI JavaScript. I think you should have something that looks more like this:

```
ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/SCRIPTS/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", false);
ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/SCRIPTS/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js", false);
...
```

And you might want a `CssRegistration.Register` for the jQuery-UI stylesheet as well. I don't know what your `jquery-ui.js` is called so I guessed.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  You are right, I forgot about the ui library and css

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't including jQuery more than once. The second one will reset any earlier plugins you have already added to the rendered HTML.